# Error after installing mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I Installed mongoose and now I can not run my server.
The below is the error.

[image]

Any methods to solve this in windows?

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the MongoDB daemon running.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

The error you are getting is saying that you don't have MongoDB running on the default port (27017) on your local machine.